# Consideration for building shared storage for VMware environment DR site

Tags: replication, storage-area-network, hp

I am investigating the of which one is the most preferable choice for DR environment ?

#### between SAN based replication technology or 3rd party application (Veeam Backup and replication or VMware Site Recovery mgr.)

my current situation is that I have running mostly virtual environment

production environment that is mixed of HP DL 380 and Blade servers with EMC Clariion CX4-500 FC-SAN
planning for DR environment that uses the same server model but still thinking of which SAN technology that we could use for the replication between the two sites ?

The DR site is not necessarily to be as fast as the current production and the SAN doesn't have to be EMC

Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't speak on Veeam Backup and replication or SRM yet, but may I suggest vReplicator?  For replication I have been using vReplicator, a third party solution, by Quest software/Vizioncore.  It has been working great for the past 3 months.  The software uses CBT (change block tracking) and gives you a couple different replication methods (differential or hybrid).  The software is also DRS and HA aware, so the job will continue if there is a guest migration.

The software can alert to a mailing group, our backup group, if a failure occurs and if the remote/local SANs are filling up.

Comment: wow, thanks for your reply mate, so does this software can also runs across different SAN vendor and subnet ?

Comment: Yeah vreplicator doesn't care about SAN tech, as long as its connected to the network. http://vizioncore.com/product/vReplicator/ I move from a Fiber connected SAN attached to vSphere to an iSCSI SAN w/ a vsphere host on the other end.You can crank the replication up to 5 minute intervals if you RTO is near current.

Answer (score 1):

I been using Veeam in our HP dl380 environment for 2 years now. It works perfectly across all networks, hardware, and host os. I have everything on VMWare and as long as your replication site is in VMWare you can use whatever hardware you want. I currently run a three tier system using Veeam backup onsite, replication offsite, and backup copy over a VPN offsite. I looked at the SAN replication, but the issue there is you usually have to the same SAN hardware at both locations which can be expensive. I would highly recommend Veeam, it's reliable, quick to deploy, and easy to use.

Comment: Did you try SRM? Do you need to failover whole site instead of an individual VMs?